# What to pass to useField hook - Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have following component created with Formik. I took this example from docs and web examples from other users. I am just curious, why we are passing name as argument into useField hook? What this argument tell us? What it is for?

```js
import React from "react";
import { useField, Formik } from "formik";

const MyTextField = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const [field] = useField(name);
  return (
    <>
      <input {...field} {...props} />
    </>
  );
};

export const Example = () => {
  const customHandler = () => {
    console.log("I am custom function");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Form</h1>
      <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={() => {}}>
        {() => (
          <>
            <MyTextField
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="Firstname"
              type="text"
              label="First Name"
              onChange={customHandler}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: so concept behind have a hook to handle fields is for keeping the track of values for a perticular field, as name is a unique identifier in a form for a field. there is more to useField than just field value mapping, check here https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#reference